# Pick out types of links in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, toggle

I have an html page with a div called links, inside this div I have a number of links, some to websites and others pdf. I would like to be able to use jQuery so that when a button is clicked only the pdf links will show. I am quite new to jQuery and was wondering how I could do this.

Comment: You could give the PDF links a specific class and show/hide links based on that criteria. I would help to see the code you've got and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

At first load JQuery in your html file: and you could use this sample code:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     //create variable and hide it at start
     var pdf_links = $("#pdf_links").hide();

     //onclick function with show function
     $("button").click(function(){
         pdf_links.show();
     });
    });
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors function very similar to [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), so you can just select anchor tags with hrefs ending in `.pdf` like this: `$('a[href$=".pdf"]')`

To only show pdf links on click, you could hide all links and then only show the pdf ones like so:

```
/*** Onload Event, so it waits until stuff actually exist ***/
$(function(){
    $('#myBtn').click(function() {
        /*** $().hide basically adds a display:none to the element. Hides all links in div. ***/
        $('#links > a').hide();

        /*** Opposite of $().hide(); Applied to PDF links ***/
        $('#links > a[href$=".pdf"]').show();
    });
});
```

[jQuery Selectors Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: Can you please clarify? What is your current HTML structure? Note that the way it's currently written, the links must be directly inside the div with an ID of "links." Example: https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/yb2k0yat/

You can remove the `>` to select all links inside the div, or you may need to select it by another identifier (ie. `$('.class')` or `$('div')`).

Comment: it's written inside a div with an ID links

Comment: Can you please post an edit to your question containing the code you have now?